# Constructing solutions for a given series to make it convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

I would like to find a function f such that $$y_i=f(i) \geq 0$$ such that:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n y_i = C(1-\frac{3p}{4})^{n(1-\frac{3p}{4})}(\frac{3p}{4})^{n(\frac{3p}{4})},$$

where $$C > 0, 0 \leq p \leq 1,$$ and

$$\sum_{w=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^n (-\frac{1}{3})^k\binom{n-i}{w-k}\binom{i}{k}3^{i}y_i$$ converges to a constant as $$n\rightarrow \infty.$$

Do you have any ideas? First of all, suggestions how to decompose the first sum would be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $C$? If it is a constant independent on $n$ then for $C=1$ then $y_i=y_i(1)$ are determined uniquely, so we have only to check the convergence of the sum. For any other $C$ $y_i=y_i(C)=C(y_i(1))$, which doesn’t change the convergence of the sum.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. $C$ is a constant independent of $n$. However, I am not sure if I understand your notation. By $y_i=f(i)$ I mean that $y$'s are generated by some function of $i$. What do you mean by $y_i(1)$?

Comment: By $y_i(1)$ I mean the (uniquely determined) value of $y_i$ when $C$ is $1$.

Comment: I see, yeah. My problem is to actually find which function may work here. I put $C$ to remember that I can scale without changing the convergence.

Comment: If $p=0$ we encounter undefined expression $0^0$, but if $p>0$ then the function $f$ is defined uniquely by $y_0=C$ and $y_i=C(1-\frac{3p}{4})^{i(1-\frac{3p}{4})}(\frac{3p}{4})^{i(\frac{3p}{4})}- C(1-\frac{3p}{4})^{(i-1)(1-\frac{3p}{4})}(\frac{3p}{4})^{(i-1)(\frac{3p}{4})}$ for $i>1$.